# Is it a bad idea to use painted MDF for vanity unit doors in a bathroom? And what would be the best way to seal it?

Tags: bathroom, painting, carpentry, vanity, mdf

I need to replace the (chipboard) doors of an old vanity unity. I only have MDF and melamine on hand, and I don't want to use the melamine as it is a different thickness to what I need.

Is it a bad idea to use the MDF, provided I undercoat and paint it?

Is there some other product I can use to seal it further?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kitchen and bath cabinets of Ikea are made of MDF or particleboard, with melamine, polyurethane and acrylic finishes depending on the cost point.

You write "I only have MDF and melamine on hand", and by that I take it you mean you have unfinished MDF board, and some particle board with a melamine foil finish.

If you have unfinished MDF, painting it with acrylic (after an optional primer/undercoater) will suffice for vertical surfaces that will not endure standing water.

Remember that "drywall" walls in kitchens and bathrooms are also just paper & gypsum, covered by acrylic primer & paint. They withstand humidity and a small amount of regular splash.

Coating further with a more durable furniture paint, that contains melamine, would provide much better protection.

MDF is "thirsty" as they say, so use several coats of primer to seal it well, before applying the more expensive melamine coat.

Comment: I would disagree that primer is "optional", especially if it is raw. A single coat of a solvent based primer should also only require a single coat and should suffice.   +1 for the rest of your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Normal MDF is not moisture-resistant.  So, I think it's a very bad idea.  Not only will moisture get in but a small leak will also make it like mush,

There are moisture resistant manufactured for this purpose such as [Customwood® SuperEco](https://www.customwood.co.nz/super_eco.php)

I am not associated with this site.  I deliberately chose this, because it is unlikely you will be buying in NZ.